# Flutter GetX state management initial null value

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, state-management, flutter-getx, flutter-packages

This is what I'm trying to achieve using flutter GetX package but not working properly.

I have a Firestore document, if the document is changed I want to call an api and keep the data up to date as observable.

The code below seems to work but initial screen shows null error then it shows the data.

I don't know how I can make sure both **fetchFirestoreUser()** and **fetchApiData()** (async methods) returns data before I move to the home screen.

GetX **StateMixin** seems to help with async data load problem but then I don't know how I can refresh the api data when the firestore document is changed.

I'm not sure if any other state management would be best for my scenario but I find GetX easy compared to other state management package.

I would very much appreciate if someone would tell me how I can solve this problem, many thanks in advance.

### Auth Controller.

```
class AuthController extends SuperController {
  static AuthController instance = Get.find();
  late Rx<User?> _user;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  var _firestoreUser = FirestoreUser().obs;
  var _apiData = ProfileUser().obs;

  @override
  void onReady() async {
    super.onReady();

    _user = Rx<User?>(auth.currentUser);
    _user.bindStream(auth.userChanges());

    //get firestore document
    fetchFirestoreUser();

    //fetch data from api
    fetchApiData();

    ever(_user, _initialScreen);

    //Refresh api data if firestore document has changed.
    _firestoreUser.listen((val) {
      fetchApiData();
    });
  }

  Rx<FirestoreUser?> get firestoreUser => _firestoreUser;

  _initialScreen(User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      Get.offAll(() => Login());
    } else {
      Get.offAll(() => Home());
    }
  }

  ProfileUser get apiData => _apiData.value;

  void fetchFirestoreUser() async {
    Stream<FirestoreUser> firestoreUser =
        FirestoreDB().getFirestoreUser(_user.value!.uid);
    _firestoreUser.bindStream(firestoreUser);
  }

  fetchApiData() async {
    var result = await RemoteService.getProfile(_user.value!.uid);
    if (result != null) {
      _apiData.value = result;
    }
  }

  @override
  void onDetached() {}

  @override
  void onInactive() {}

  @override
  void onPaused() {}

  @override
  void onResumed() {
    fetchApiData();
  }
}
```

### Home screen

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
            child: Obx(() =>
                Text("username: " + AuthController.instance.apiData.username!))),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Basically when you go to your page initially it shows error then puts the data right?

Comment: correct, null error initially

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I never used GetX so I'm not too familiar with that syntax.

But I can see from your code that you're setting some mutable state when you call this method:

```
  fetchApiData() async {
    var result = await RemoteService.getProfile(_user.value!.uid);
    if (result != null) {
      _apiData.value = result;
    }
  }
```

Instead, a more robust solution would be to make everything reactive and immutable. You could do this by combining providers if you use Riverpod:

```
final authStateChangesProvider = StreamProvider.autoDispose<User?>((ref) {
  final authService = ref.watch(authRepositoryProvider);
  return authService.authStateChanges();
});

final apiDataProvider = FutureProvider.autoDispose<APIData?>((ref) {
  final userValue = ref.watch(authStateChangesProvider);
  final user = userValue.value;
  if (user != null) {
    // note: this should also be turned into a provider, rather than using a static method
    return RemoteService.getProfile(user.uid);
  } else {
    // decide if it makes sense to return null or throw and exception when the user is not signed in
    return Future.value(null);
  }
});
```

Then, you can just use a **ConsumerWidget** to **watch** the data:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    // this will cause the widget to rebuild whenever the auth state changes 
    final apiData = ref.watch(apiDataProvider);
    return apiData.when(
      data: (data) => /* some widget */,
      loading: () => /* some loading widget */,
      error: (e, st) => /* some error widget */,
    );
  }
```

Note: Riverpod has a bit of a learning curve (worth it imho) so you'll have to learn it how to use it first, before you can understand how this code works.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a try and let you know, thank you for for the detailed answer.

Comment: I'm getting there, I need to call the api data when a firestore document changes not authStateChanges but I'm getting Error type 'Null' is not a subtype of bool. code sample below.

Comment: Posted a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70731629/flutter-make-http-api-call-when-firestore-document-changed

Answer (score 0):

Actually the reason behind this that you put your `controller` in the same page that you are calling so in the starting stage of your page **Get.put()** calls your `controller` and because you are fetching data from the `API` it takes a few `seconds/milliseconds` to get the data and for that time your **Obx()** renders the error. To prevent this you can apply some `conditional` logic to your code like below :

```
Obx(() => AuthController.instance.apiData != null ? Text("username: " + AuthController.instance.apiData.username!) : CircularProgressIndicator())) :
```

Comment: I've lot more data in home screen than shown in the code sample. Is there way to display progress indicator if apiData object is null?

Comment: Your all data is from same controller or diffrent?

Comment: yes, from the same controller

Comment: Then just wrap all your content in the Obx and aply the same logic