# Flutter make http api call when Firestore document changed

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, riverpod

I'm trying to call data api when a firestore document is changed but I'm getting error: **Error type 'null' is not a subtype of 'bool'** with riverpod. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

```
final firebaseAuthProvider = Provider<FirebaseAuth>((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance);
```

```
final authStateChangesProvider = StreamProvider<User?>((ref) => ref.watch(firebaseAuthProvider).authStateChanges());
```

```
final databaseProvider = Provider<DatabaseService?>((ref) {
  final auth = ref.watch(authStateChangesProvider);

  if (auth.asData?.value?.uid != null) {
    return DatabaseService(uid: auth.asData!.value!.uid);
  }
  return null;
});
```

```
final firestoreDatabaseProvider = Provider<FirestoreDatabase?>((ref) {
  final auth = ref.watch(authStateChangesProvider);

  if (auth.asData?.value?.uid != null) {
    return FirestoreDatabase(uid: auth.asData!.value!.uid);
  }
  return null;
});
```

```
final apiDataProvider2 = FutureProvider.autoDispose<ProfileUser?>((ref) {
  final authUser = ref.watch(authStateChangesProvider);
  final user = authUser.value;
  if (user != null) {
    final userValue = ref.watch(firestoreDatabaseProvider);
    final dbProvider = ref.watch(databaseProvider);
    var profileUser;
    userValue?.getFirestoreUser().listen((event) {
      profileUser = dbProvider!.getProfile();
    });

    if (profileUser) {
      return profileUser;
    } else {
      return Future.value(null);
    }
  } 
});
```

Comment: i don't know how to solve it but when this happenned to me in react it was mainly cause the authenticated user object wasn't fully loaded or you're making some servertimestamp changes and the snapshot update gets triggered before the time's been set by the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `profileUser`; It is being returned before

```
   var profileUser;
    userValue?.getFirestoreUser().listen((event) {
      profileUser = dbProvider!.getProfile();
    });

    if (profileUser) {
      return profileUser;
    } else {
      return Future.value(null);
    }
```

Try this instead:

```
   var profileUser = (await userValue?.getFirestoreUser().first)!.getProfile();
    if (profileUser) {
      return profileUser;
    } else {
      return Future.value(null);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I'l give that a try